# Reflection in real-world application

Tags: java, reflection, encapsulation

Why and where should I use Reflection, I understand that you can get acess to the field by it's name but why should I use it?

Comment: "why should I use it" - you shouldn't unless you _really_ know what you're doing and are out of other meaningful options. I'd suggest you learn about what reflection can do (the good and especially the bad). That way it should become much clearer.

Comment: Never use it, just as you could use the the maintenance ladder of the elevator shaft. It is for language tools.

Comment: you can see：[What is reflection and why is it useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)